# How to associate multiple profiles per user with Profile2

Tags: users, version-control

I'm running a Drupal 7 site that has different profile types (created using the Profile2 module). Each user is associated with a profile, so at the time of registration, a potential user can choose a specific profile, and based on that, a different registration page is displayed.

I was wondering, is it possible to allow a normal user (not admin) to associate more than one profile for itself? So that he/she can see the fields of each specific profile to which is associated?

At present, the Profile2 module allow to have one User: one Profile relationship, and only the admin can add multiple profiles to a user. Is there a patch for Profile2 module to permit this kind of feature? 
Thank you!

Comment: It's definitely possible to let a user have multiple Profile2 profiles, so your configuration must be wrong  - `Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile)`

Comment: @ColinShipton Yes, it's possible to associate multiple profile types to a specific user, but that can be made by the admin and not the user itself, with it's own profile. Which permission do you mean in this case?

Comment: Have you looked through https://www.drupal.org/node/1074296 - `By default profiles can be created and edited at user/uid/edit. There should be a secondary tab for each profile the user has access to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the solution with [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation) module, and by setting the right permissions offered by this module.